# React displaying sum of child components values not accurate

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components

I am trying to display a sum of all of child component lists values but it is not accurate, because it keeps the previous value in the array too, how could I work around this?

the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = styled.div `
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
`;

class ShoppingList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    questions: [''],
    sum: 0
  }

  handleText = i => e => {
    console.log('id', this.state.id);
    let questions = [...this.state.questions];
    questions[i] = parseInt(e.target.value);
    if (questions.length === 1 && isNaN(questions[0])) {
      questions[0] = ''
    }
    let sum = questions.reduce(function(a, b) {
      if (isNaN(a)) {
        a = '';
      }
      if (isNaN(b)) {
        b = '';
      }
      return a + b;
    });
    console.log('sum', sum);
    this.props.value(sum);
    this.setState({
      questions,
      sum
    })
  }

  addExpense = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let questions = this.state.questions.concat([''])
    this.setState({
      questions
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container>
          <select>
            <option value="food">Food</option>
            <option value="houseware">Houseware</option>
            <option value="entertainment">Entertainment</option>
          </select>
          <button onClick={this.addExpense}>Add expense</button>
        </Container>
        {this.state.questions.map((question, index) => (
          <Container  key={index}>
            <input
              type="text"
            />
            <input
              type="number"
              onChange={this.handleText(index)}
              value={question}
            />
          </Container>
        ))}
        <Container>
          <label>Total:</label>
          <label>{this.state.sum ? this.state.sum + ' €' : 0 + ' €'}</label>
        </Container>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ShoppingList;
```

and:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ShoppingList2 from './ShoppingList2';

const Container = styled.div `
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
`;

class TotalPrice extends React.Component {
  state = {
    shoppingLists2: [ShoppingList2],
    shoplistsums: [],
    sum: 0
  }

  AddShoppingList = () => {
    let shoppingLists2 = this.state.shoppingLists2.concat(ShoppingList2);
    console.log(shoppingLists2);
    this.setState({
      shoppingLists2
    })
  }

  onUpdate = (val) => {
    console.log('val', val);
    let shoplistsums = this.state.shoplistsums.concat(val);
    let sum = shoplistsums.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    });
    this.setState({
      shoplistsums,
      sum
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.shoppingLists2.map((ShoppingList2, index)=>(
          <ShoppingList2
            key={index}
            value={this.onUpdate}
          />
        ))}
        <Container>
          <label>Total:</label>
          <label>{this.state.sum + ' €'}</label>
          <button onClick={this.AddShoppingList}>Add Receipt</button>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TotalPrice;
```

here is how it looks and works and the problem: [image]

I just started to work with react recently, so if you have other suggestions, please let me know!

Comment: Looks like questions is an array of strings. How are you getting the sum by adding up an array of strings? It would be better if the questions in the state where an object with the the question(string) and the value(number) then for sum add app the values(numbers).

Comment: questions[i] = parseInt(e.target.value); it is parsed in the ShoppingList

Comment: What is a question supposed to be in your design. Food, Houseware entertainment? or are they categories?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

fixed, you can check it out @  - https://github.com/benonymus/timetravel